# array default object mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema and I want to provide a default value but anytime I provide that, I run into an error. This is the schema object value I want to provide a default value for and how I currently pass it.

```
statusData: {
        type: [
            
            {
                status: { ...trimmedString, required: false, default: 'new' },
                createdAt: {
                    type: SchemaTypes.Date,
                    required: false,
                    default: Date.now
                },
                updatedAt: {
                    type: SchemaTypes.Date,
                    required: false,
                    default: null
                },
            },
        ],
        default: [ {
            status: 'new',
            createdAt: Date.now,
            updatedAt: null
        }],
      }
```

But I get this error every time.

> validation failed: statusData.0.createdAt: Cast to date failed for
> value "[Function: now]" at path "createdAt""

any help on how I can provide a default value here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently casting a function to the default value, not the return of the function.

You also can't pass the return of the function straight in or it will reset the `createdAt` every time to the current date.

Instead, add a callback function to the default value that returns `Date.now()`

```
createdAt: {
  type: SchemaTypes.Date,
  required: false,
  default: () => Date.now()
},
```

Also, it wouldn't be a bad idea to pass `immutable: true` to the createdAt value, since likely that should never change.

Comment: without this `default: [ {
            status: 'new',
            createdAt: Date.now,
            updatedAt: null
        }` I had no problem. Providing a default value for the array is the issue here

Comment: Either way, my answer still stands.  Use the callback function `() => Date.new()` instead of passing in `Date.new`.